# iOS 10: issue with timezone when dealing with dates from HealthKit

Tags: ios, timezone, healthkit

I am writing an app with iOS 10 that extract information from HealthKit, getting the samples from BodyMass, from which I extract the date of the measure and the weight.
In the simulator, I have entered some values:
Date: 7 Sep, 16:52 - Weight: 92,3
Date: 8 Sep, 16:52 - Weight: 92,1

When the application reads the first date from HKQuantitySample, I get: 2016-09-07 14:52:00 +0000

I have a 2 hours difference between the date as seen from the standard health application, and the date retrieved by my app, this difference corresponding to the GMT+2 of my current location.

How should I proceed to get the date as it can be seen from the health app?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at retrieving the `HKMetadataKeyTimeZone` metadata property. Good clients should be storing the timezone information in this key so you can present the correct time back to your user.

Comment: 'Good clients', so other than the third-party apps, is Apple's Health App storing timezone information in the health samples? I have checked 'HKMetadataKeyTimeZone' for the health data created by Apple's Health App and it is ni.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250964/hkmetadatakeytimezone-is-always-nil-for-health-data-which-is-created-by-apples