# What is the timezone in which the current steps are calculated in healthKit? Is it UTC or the device timezone? What if the user changes timezones?

Tags: ios, healthkit

What is the timezone in which the current steps are calculated in healthKit? Is it UTC or the device timezone? What if the user changes timezones? How will it impact the healthkit data?

Comment: What are you trying to do where this information is needed?

Comment: I have n application which counts user steps. So what if the user travels across different countries. I have the app running in singapore, India, Hungry, US etc. So in gmt+12 the steps calculated increase by 1.  The steps array I get is different for different timezones.

Comment: Time zone shouldn't affect the data that is collected. HKSamples are recorded with NSDates, which reflect absolute time that is independent of the time zone. You may be computing dates on the predicates for your queries in a way that depends on time zone, though. Could you include a code snippet and a more precise description of what results you're getting and how they differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 4):

The `startDate` and `endDate` of HKSample objects are NSDate values, and thus contain no time zone information (see the overview of [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate) documentation for more info). Technically I wouldn't say that NSDate values are UTC dates, but you can think of them that way.

This means that, looking at just the startDate/endDate of a sample, you cannot tell what the *local* time was for the user when the sample was recorded. For example, if the user has moved around across time zones, you may not be able to determine whether a sample was actually recorded 11:30 pm Friday local time or 12:30 am Saturday in some other location.

There is a standard key [`HKMetadataKeyTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeytimezone) that can be used to store the original time zone in sample's `metadata` dictionary. This would give you exactly the information you need, but you can't rely on it actually being present. Apple doesn't even populate the time zone metadata for health data recorded natively by the iPhone or Apple Watch (see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49250964/795339) for further discussion).